# Reading a CSV file using another class then login java

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a CSV file from another class then take the details and compare them with the login information given by the user in the main class. I can do it by putting everything in the main class but it doesn't look very neat.

--Main--

```
package supscription.service;

/**
 *
 * @author jakec
 */
import java.util.*;
public class SubscriptionService {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String username;
    String password;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Log in:");
    System.out.println("username: ");
    username = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("password: ");
    password = input.nextLine();

    users check = new users(username, password);

    if(check.auth()) 
        System.out.println("You are logged in");
    else
        System.out.println("Log in failed");
    }

}
```

--users--

```
 public class users {

private String username;
private String password;
private  String File = ("MEMBER.csv");
Scanner scan = new Scanner (SubscriptionService.class.getResourceAsStream(File)).useDelimiter(",");
String user = scan.nextLine();
String pass = scan.nextLine();

public users(String user, String pass){
    username = user;
    password = pass;
}

public boolean auth(){
    if((username.equals (user)) && (password.equals (pass)))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

}
```

--The CSV--

```
Member_ID,Username,Password
11001,Jack Brown,123
11009,James White,12
11014,Barbara Jones,58
...
```

Comment: It seems like this question might be more appropriate on `CodeReview.SE` but I would just mention that storing passwords in the clear is fine for an exercise but not for production code, and that parsing a CSV file this way will fail if the data is `11007,"Brian Green, Jr.",123456`. I would use [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Comment: Yeah I know that, don't worry I'm only using it as a practice and thank you for pointing me towards code review I'll have a look cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your approch is correct. To search for a particular user, you need to first read all the users and store them in let's say a `list`. You can do the following:

1. Create a `user` class to hold user information
2. Create a method to read all the users
3. Create a method to search user

For Step 1, the user class can have id, username and password , e,g.:

```
class User{

    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User(int id, String username, String password){
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

For Step 2, you can create a service class and read all the users, e.g.:

```
class Users{

    private static List<User> users;

    public static synchronized void readUsers(){
        if(null == users){
            users = new ArrayList<User>();
            String File = ("MEMBER.csv");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (Users.class.getResourceAsStream(File));
            String line;
            while((line = scan.nextLine()) != null){
                String[] tokens = line.split(",");
                users.add(new User(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]), tokens[1], tokens[2]));
            }
            scan.close();
        }
    }
}
```

For Step 3, you need to add another method in service class which will search into the list and return `true` or `false`, e.g.:

```
public static synchronized boolean find(String username, String password){
    if(null == users){
        throw new IllegalStateException("user list is not initialised");
    }

    return users.stream()
            .filter(u -> u.getUsername().equals(username))
            .filter(u -> u.getPassword().equals(password))
            .findFirst()
            .isPresent();
}
```

This would return `true` or `false` based on whether `User` exists in the list.

In your `main` class, you can use the following flow:

- Initialise User list
- Read username and password via command line
- Call `find` method and print appropriate output

Please note that all the methods in `Users` class are `static` so you don't need to create an object. You can call the methods directly, e.g. `Users.readUsers();`

Comment: I've changed main class but I am getting the error that the List hasn't been initilised:

Comment: Don't know what happened there. I've changed main class but I am getting the error that the List hasn't been initialised. This is how I've initialised it: List<UsersReader> users = new ArrayList(); I've called the services class UsersReader.