# Read individual columns from a csv into corrisponding arraylists java

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I am trying to take columns out of an CSV split by "," and then put it in to an arraylist. For example my CSV looks like this:

```
Member_ID,Member Name
11001,Jack Brown
11009,James White
11014,Barbara Jones
```

So I want to put everything under the memberId column into an arrayList called IDs.

Here's my current code:

```
            String File = ("MEMBER.csv");
            Scanner read = new Scanner(SubscriptionService.class.getResourceAsStream(File));
            read.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
            ArrayList<String> IDs = new ArrayList<>();
            read.nextLine();
            while (read.hasNext()) {
                IDs.add(read.next());
            }
            System.out.println("Member_ID Username");
            for (int i = 0; i < IDs.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(IDs.get(i));
            }
```

When I print to see what is in the IDs arraylist it prints everything and not just the IDs like so:

```
11001
Jack Brown
11009
James White
11014
Barbara Jones
```

really want to try and avoid using other libraries such as Open CSV.

Comment: Have you forgot you asked this question a month before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42190886/411604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general remark, it is not advisable to do "custom" `CSV` parsing, as above. For any production environment, a mature library (like `OpenCSV`) should be preferred.

Having said so, this is a trivial I/O task that can probably be better implemented using a `BufferedReader` instead of a `Scanner`. The `ArrayList` is not the most suitable data structure for storing data of this type, unless of course only one of the `CSV` columns is required.

Nevertheless, assuming that the input file consists of lines that are of the form presented in the post, a method to read any such file given its name, is:

```
  public static void read(String name) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(SubscriptionService.class.getResourceAsStream(name)));
    ArrayList<String> IDs = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    String[] tokens;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      tokens = line.split(",");
      if (tokens.length != 2) { // Skip any "weird" (e.g., empty) line
        continue;
      }
      IDs.add(tokens[0].trim());
      names.add(tokens[1].trim());
    }
    System.out.println("Member_ID\tUsername");
    for (int i = 0; i < IDs.size(); i++) { // IDs and names have the same size
      System.out.println(IDs.get(i) + "\t" + names.get(i));
    }
  }
```

The method uses a `BufferedReader` to read the input file line-by-line in a standardized way and stores the data in 2 `ArrayList` objects, one for the IDs and another for the names. The `trim()` method is used to remove any spaces before or after the comma separator.

After reading the entire file, the `read()` method prints the results line-by-line, separating the 2 fields by a `tab` character (`\t`).

If only printing the IDs are required, the code can be edited accordingly. In that case, the method can also be modified to return the `IDs` `ArrayList`.